# Error in handling session via socket.io using handshake in Express, NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, socket.io

```
I am developing basic application that has a simple membership. Besides, i need to develop Sessions aswell. In my following code, sockets do not respond. Can you help me to find the reason behind that ?
```

app.js

```js
var WebApp = require('./webApp.js');
var db = require('./db/db.js');
var db = new db();
var webApp = new WebApp();
var App = function(){}
webApp.initialize();
webApp.socketIOConnect(function(client){

  webApp.socketIOConnectMethods(client);


});

module.exports = App;
```

webApp.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var Db = require('./db/db.js');
var connect = require('connect');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var socketHandshake = require('socket.io-handshake');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.use(socketHandshake({secret:'secret',resave : false, saveUninitialized : true, parser:cookieParser()}));
server.listen(1185);
var WebApp = function () {
  console.log("Greetings from WebApp Module.");
}
var db = new Db();
WebApp.prototype.initialize = function () {

    app.use(express.static("./assets"));
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile("./assets/index.html");
    });
    router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve("./assets/login.html"));
    });
    router.get('/client', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve("./client/client.html"));
    });
    app.use(router);
}
WebApp.prototype.socketIOConnect = function(callback) {

    io.on('connection', function(client, req, res) {

        callback(client)
      });

}

WebApp.prototype.socketIOConnectMethods = function (client) {

          if (client.handshake.session.name) {
            console.log('We already know you!');
            client.emit('get name');
            client.emit('redirect');
          };

          client.on('join', function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          });
          client.on('register', function(data) {
              client.emit('username', data);
              console.log(data);
              var checkAuth;
              var username = data.user;
              var password = data.passw;
              var email = data.email;
              var confpass = data.confirmPass;
              console.log("password : "+password);
              console.log("conf password :"+confpass);
              if ( password == confpass){
                console.log("Passwords match, this lad can login");
                var values = [[, username, password, email]];
                console.log(username + " " + password + " " + email);
                db.registAuth(email,function(err, results) {
                    if (err) {

                        console.log("An error occurred: " + err.message);
                    }
                    client.on('passwordmatches',function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                    });
                    console.log(results);
                    var checkAuth = results.length;
                    if(results < 1){
                      db.userRegistration(values,function(err, results) {
                          if(err) {
                              console.log("An error occurred: " + err.message);
                          }
                          console.log(results);
                      });//user registration
                    }
                    else{console.log("Sorry, we could not complete your registration. Email already exists.");}
                  });//registAuth
              }
              else{
                client.on('NoMatchPass',function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                });
                console.log("Sorry, we could not complete your registration. Passwords do not match !");
                client.emit('tryagainreg',"Sorry, we could not complete your registration. Passwords do not match !");
              }

          });//client.on register
          client.on('login', function(data) {
              var email = data.email;
              var password = data.password;
              console.log(data);
              db.loginAuth(email, password, function(err, results) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.log("An error occurred: " + err.message);
                  }
                  console.log(results.length);
                  if ( results.length == 1){
                    console.log("Welcome, "+email+"!");
                    client.handhsake.session.name = email;
                    client.handshake.session.save();
                    console.log(client.handshake.session.name);
                    client.emit('AuthLogin',email);
                  }
                  else{console.log("Wrong username or password.");
                      client.emit('FailedLogin',email);
                }

              });
            });
};
module.exports = WebApp;
```

I want user to login when they completed their registration successfully and then, when they logged in successfully i want to redirect them client.html but with session so that i can keep them authorized till they logged out of the applicaton.

login.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

 <title>Let's Get Head In</title>

 <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

 <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

 <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./css/material-kit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body class="signup-page">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-absolute">
     <div class="container">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">AslanServices</a>
         </div>

         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-example">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li>
         <a href="./index.html" target="">
          Register
         </a>
        </li>
        <li>
      <a href="" target="">
       <i class="material-icons">unarchive</i>Contact
      </a>
        </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header header-filter" style="background-image: url('./img/city.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: top center;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="card card-signup">
       <form class="loginform" method="" action="">
        <div class="header header-primary text-center">
         <h4>Sign In</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="content">

         <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="material-icons">email</i>
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email...">
         </div>

         <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
          </span>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password" class="form-control" />
         </div>

         <!-- If you want to add a checkbox to this form, uncomment this code

         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" checked>
           Subscribe to newsletter
          </label>
         </div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="footer text-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">Sign in!</button>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <footer class="footer">
          <div class="container">
              <nav class="pull-left">
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ozercevikaslan/">
         AslanServices
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ozercevikaslan/">
           About Us
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
              </nav>
              <div class="copyright pull-right">
                  &copy; 2017, made by <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ozercevikaslan/" target="_blank">Aslanmeister</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </footer>

  </div>

    </div>


</body>
 <!--   Core JS Files   -->
 <script src="./js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/material.min.js"></script>

 <!--  Plugin for the Sliders, full documentation here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->
 <script src="./js/nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!--  Plugin for the Datepicker, full documentation here: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ -->
 <script src="./js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!-- Control Center for Material Kit: activating the ripples, parallax effects, scripts from the example pages etc -->
 <script src="./js/material-kit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
            var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:1185');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
                      socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
       socket.on('redirect',function(callback){         callback(window.location.href="127.0.0.1:1185/client");
        });
      $('form.loginform').submit(function(event){
                         event.preventDefault();
                         var email = $('#email').val();
                         var password = $('#password').val();
                  socket.emit('login',{email : email, password : password});
                  socket.on('AuthLogin',function(data){window.location.href = 127.0.0.1:1185/client";});
                  socket.on('FailedLogin',function(data){alert('Wrong username or Password. Maybe, you dont even exist!');window.location.href = "127.0.0.1:1185";});
                    });
        });
      </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved my problem by using this code below.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var Db = require('./db/db.js');
var connect = require('connect');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cookieParser('aslan'));
var redis   = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var cookie = require('cookie');
//var passwordHash = require('password-hash');
var redisclient  = redis.createClient();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true }));
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new RedisStore({host : 'localhost'  , port : '6379' , client : redisclient , ttl : 15}), //  redis server config
    secret: 'aslan',
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : false
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
//---------------CONFIG PART ENDED-------------
    app.get('/',function (req, res, next) {
      session = req.session;
      if ( session.key ){
          res.redirect('/'+session.key+'');
      }
        res.sendFile("./assets/index.html");
    });
//---------------------------------
    app.get('/login', function (req,res,next) {
      session = req.session;
      if ( session.key ){
          if ( session.key == 'admin@gmail.com'){res.redirect('/admin');}
          if ( session.key != 'admin@gmail.com'){res.redirect('/'+session.key);}
      }
        res.sendFile(path.resolve("./assets/login.html"));

    });
    //--------------------------------LOGIN POST------------------
    app.post('/login', function (req,res,next) {
      console.log("hi from login post");
      var email = req.body.user.email;
      var password = req.body.user.password;
      db.loginAuth(email, password, function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("An error occurred: " + err.message);
          }
          console.log(results.length);
          if ( results.length == 1){
            console.log("Welcome, "+email+"!");
            //session
            session = req.session;
            session.key = email;
            db.returnUsername(session.key,function(err,result){
                if (err) {
                  console.log('An Error Occured in Db :' + err.message);
                }
                console.log(result);
                console.log(session.key+'Before checking');
                if ( session.key == 'admin@gmail.com'){console.log('Session key is equal to admin@gmail.com'); res.redirect('/admin');}
                if ( session.key != 'admin@gmail.com'){console.log('Session key is not equal to admin@gmail.com'); res.redirect('/evsahibi');}
                 
            });
            
          }
          else{console.log("Wrong username or password.");}
      });
    });
```